# How to display uploaded pdf file along with machine name and operation number based on select from dropdown

Tags: django

In this project, I want to display machine name and operation number along with uploaded pdf files based on select machine name and operation number from dropdown menu. This project is working but when I add and select another file in same machine name and operation number, it is displaying two pdf files along with previous pdf file of another machine name and operation number, exactly I don't want it. It should display machine name and operation number along with uploaded pdf file based on select from dropdown menu. And also when I upload another pdf files in same machine name and operation number, it should display two pdf files along with same machine name and operation number within same row.
This project is working fine but I want above validations.
Please anyone can help me out, this will be great for me. Please..

**views.py:**

```
def upload(request):
    controlmachines = Controlmachine.objects.all()
    return render(request,'usermaster/upload.html',{'machines':machines})

def save_machine(request):
   if request.method == "POST":
      machine_name = request.POST.get('machinename', '')
      operation_no = request.POST.get('operationname','')
      choiced_cmachine = Controlmachine.objects.filter(machine_name=machine_name, operation_no=operation_no)
      cmachines = Controlmachine.objects.all()
      return render(request,'usermaster/upload.html',{'machines':machines,'choiced_cmachine':choiced_cmachine})

def index(request):  
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ControlmachineForm(request.POST, request.FILES)  
        if form.is_valid():
           model_instance = form.save()
           model_instance.save()
   else:
        form = ControlmachineForm()
    controlmachiness = Controlmachine.objects.all()
    return render(request,'usermaster/upload_file.html',{'form':form,'controlmachiness':controlmachiness})
```

**upload.html:**

```
<form action="{% url 'save_machine' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
       <label for="machinename">Select Machine Name:</label>
       <select name="machinename" id="machinename">
           
           {% for machine in cmachines %}
           <option value="{{ machine.machine_name }}">{{ machine.machine_name }}</option>
           {% endfor %}
       </select>
       <br>
       <br>
       <label for="operationname">Select Operation Number:</label>
       <select id="operationname" name="operationname">
           
           {% for machine in cmachines %}
           <option value="{{ machine.operation_no }}">{{ machine.operation_no }}</option>
           {% endfor %}
           </select>
       <br>
       <br>
       <br>
       <input type="submit" value="Save">
   </form>

<tr>
    {% for choice in choiced_cmachine %}
    <td>{{choice.machine_name}}</td>
    <td>{{choice.operation_no}}</td>
    <td>
        {% for file in controlmachines %}
        <a href="/media/{{file.file1}}">view file</a>
        {% endfor %}
    </td>
    {% endfor %}
</tr>
```

**control_uploadfile.html:**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Master File Upload</title>

</head>
<body>
<p><h1>Control File Upload</h1></p>
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">  
        {% csrf_token %}  
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Save</button> <br><br>
</form>
</body>  
</html>
```

**control_show.html:**

```
{% extends "master/control_base.html" %}
 
{% block title %}Control File{% endblock title %}
 
{% block content %}
 <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="table-responsive">
  <table id="bootstrapdatatable" class="table table-striped table-bordered" width="90%">
            <thead>
                <th><input type="checkbox" id="checkall" /></th>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Machine Name</th>
                <th>Operation Number</th>
                <th>File</th>
                <th>Delete</th>
             </thead>
   <tbody>
   {% for control in controlmachines %}  
    <tr>  
     <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkthis" /></td>
     <td>{{ control.id }}</td>  
     <td>{{ control.machine_name }}</td>  
     <td>{{ control.operation_no }}</td>  
     <td>{{ control.control_uploadfile }}</td>  
     <td><p data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Delete"><a href="/delete/{{ control.id }}" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" data-title="Delete" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delete" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></a></p></td>  
    </tr>  
   {% endfor %} 
   </tbody>
         
  </table>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

**models.py:**

```
class Controlmachine(models.Model):  
    machine_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)  
    operation_no = models.IntegerField()  
    control_uploadfile = models.FileField(upload_to='documents/')
  
    class Meta:  
        db_table = "controlmachine"
```

**forms.py:**

```
class ControlForm(forms.ModelForm):  
    class Meta:  
        model = Controlmachine 
        fields = ['machine_name', 'operation_no', 'control_uploadfile'] #https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/widgets/
        widgets = { 'machine_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={ 'class': 'form-control' }), 
            'operation_no': forms.TextInput(attrs={ 'class': 'form-control' }),
            'control_uploadfile': forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={ 'class': 'form-control' }),
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this: Here I have added if condition that is used to connect machine name to uploaded file.

```
<form action="{% url 'save_machine' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
       <label for="machinename">Select Machine Name:</label>
       <select name="machinename" id="machinename">
           
           {% for machine in cmachines %}
           <option value="{{ machine.machine_name }}">{{ machine.machine_name }}</option>
           {% endfor %}
       </select>
       <br>
       <br>
       <label for="operationname">Select Operation Number:</label>
       <select id="operationname" name="operationname">
           
           {% for machine in cmachines %}
           <option value="{{ machine.operation_no }}">{{ machine.operation_no }}</option>
           {% endfor %}
           </select>
       <br>
       <br>
       <br>
       <input type="submit" value="Save">
   </form>

<tr>
    {% for choice in choiced_cmachine %}
    <td>{{choice.machine_name}}</td>
    <td>{{choice.operation_no}}</td>
    <td>
        {% for file in controlmachines %}
           {% if file == choice and file == choice %}
           <a href="/media/{{file.file1}}">view file</a>
           {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    </td>
    {% endfor %}
</tr>
```